# Is `global` the correct way for a class to access a module level variable?

Tags: python

I am creating an enter/exit block for a module level construct. I have the following example to test how to access the module level variable from within the class:

```
_variableScope = ''

class VariableScope(object):
  def __init__(self, scope):
    self._scope = scope

  def __enter__(self):
    global _variableScope
    _variableScope += self._scope

x = VariableScope('mytest')
x.__enter__()
print(_variableScope)
```

This gets me the expected value of `'mytest'`, but ...

Is the use of `global` inside the `__enter__()` method correct and good practice?

Comment: `global` doesn't expose something, it declares it globally, and that's usually a bad practice because it quickly leads to chaos. Why not use either a singleton or an accessor method?

Comment: You might want to read more about the `with` block and context managers. What you wrote is not how it should be done.

Comment: Why use `__enter__`? Why couldn't you simply add the `_variableScope += self._scope` line to your `__init__`.  Also, where does the "expected" value of 142 come from?  It should be 'mytest' per your example.

Comment: 42 was a typo, I fixed it. This is just a simplified and incomplete example, the class will be part of a larger module where path-like names are in use, and this allows us to prefix a set of paths using the `with` statement. The rest of the class will utilize the value, which is why I originally thought to put it at the module level but the answer given corrected that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`global` is a "code smell": something that indicates undesirable code design.  In this case, you're merely trying to create a resource for all instances of a class.  The preferred tactic is a `class attribute`: lift the variable up one level, and all instances will share that single variable:

```
class VariableScope():
    _variableScope = ''

    def __init__(self, scope):
        self._scope = scope

    def __enter__(self):
        VariableScope._variableScope += self._scope

x = VariableScope('mytest')
x.__enter__()
print(VariableScope._variableScope)

y = VariableScope('add-to-scope')
y.__enter__()
print(VariableScope._variableScope)
```

Output:

```
mytest
mytestadd-to-scope
```

Comment: To amplify this, I just grepped our relatively massive codebase across several specialties - frontend, backend, devops, data engineering, data science, etc. - and found zero instances of "global". There's basically just about never a case where you _need_ to use it.